# Background tasks in Python, check for already sent data

Tags: python, background, task, bots, discord

I have a question for experts here. I am creating background tasks for my Discord bot and I got it working as I wanted but I would like to implement a feature that will allow me to ignore data that was already sent. I am using data that is requested via requests as it changes over time.

Here is part of my code and this works as intended but I can't figure out how to add a part to check sent messages and not repeat it. I set 1 minute for testing to see does it work and this will change later on.

Thanks in advance

````py
import discord
import requests
import asyncio
import json
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import math
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import discord.utils
from itertools import cycle

client = discord.Client()
status = (['Scraping VATSIM Data','Anyone online?','What can I show you?', 'Check our social media for updates!'])
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    auto_online.start()
    # await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="VATSIM Data!"))
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def auto_online():
    # send request to vatsim data
    t = requests.get('http://cluster.data.vatsim.net/vatsim-data.json').json()
    xy = json.dumps(t)
    s = json.loads(xy)
    channel1 = client.get_channel(692681048798265347)
    # Bookins Data Display
    utc = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    # Command for displaying ATC online
    online_exists = False
    for item in s['clients']:
        if item['callsign'] in atc:
            online_exists = True
            embed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.purple())

            embed.set_author(name='VATAdria Online ATC')
            embed.add_field(name='Controller',value=item['realname'],inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Position', value=item['callsign'], inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Frequency', value=item['frequency'], inline=False)

            await channel1.send( embed=embed)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I found out how to do this via MySQL. So no answers needed for this anymore.